# Quick Liquid and Smoke doesn't work in viewport

Tags: smoke-simulation, effects

When I make smoke by *Object > Quick effect > Quick Smoke/Liquid* it appears nothing on the viewport.

Once I bake it appears just right in viewport, but still error while rendering.

I don't know what is wrong with my scene.

[image]

[this is my Blender file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K_jisi2HDGMbIAqoLiTOL-xhvt36mwzd)

Comment: Thanks for correcting my post. Since I am not an English native user, it makes a lot of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of the change to mantaflow in Blender 2.82. You will have to click the Bake Data button on the Physics Properties Shelf of the Smoke Domain, and do this every time you make a change for that change to become visible.

You also have to bake noise data separately if you have noise activated.

Comment: oh wow This is not an error or something went wrong? It's sad that I can't check the smoke in real-time. Thanks a lot anyway. now I can stop reinstalling blender

Answer (score 0):

You can set *Cache Type* to *Replay* which is the default and play the animation in viewport or change it to *Modular*, and bake.

This is a basic scene with a cube set to domain and the sphere as the smoke inflow

https://pasteboard.co/J8glxij.png

scroll down and choose modular as shown in the image

https://pasteboard.co/J8glKVT.png

then bake the data, you can bake particles separately too

https://pasteboard.co/J8glYBc.png

And you will have smoke in viewport

https://pasteboard.co/J8gmbr5.png

This is using Blender 2.83 alpha build.

Comment: Much better thanks. When you want to add more info you should edit your original answer instead, don't post a new one. One last thing, see [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) so that images aren't lost. If they go missing your answer becomes empty and very hard to follow.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! gonna follow them now thanks