# Smoke Simulation does not appear in Eevee viewport

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I was learning how to do smoke simulations today, but when I applied object -> quick smoke, and pressed play, no smoke could be seen coming out. I then tried baking the simulation, and it finally showed up, but only for a few frames. Now I want to remove the bake, and the manual tells me there is a button in the cache settings of the fluid simulation, called "free bake" which is not there.
If anyone could please tell me how I could:

1. Remove the bake of the smoke simulation and
2. see the smoke in the Eevee realtime viewport.

   [image: Failed Eevee smoke sim]

[image: No Free Bake Button]

Comment: Update: I just deleted the fluid_cache folder and removed the bake, but when I try the smoke simulation, no smoke appears. Does this have something to do with my viewport settings?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out through some extra searching that a new change was made in Blender 2.82 that removes the "live" smoke simulation in rendered view. We now have to bake the simulation everytime we want to see something different.

I found another thread about this problem:
[Quick Liquid and Smoke doesn't work in viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166948/quick-liquid-and-smoke-doesnt-work-in-viewport)